# Error while using pywhatkit to make handwriting says "unable to access api"

Tags: python

I am getting this error while using pywhatkit:

> pywhatkit.core.exceptions.UnableToAccessApi: Unable to access Pywhatkit api right now

This is my code:

```
import pywhatkit as pw
txt = """it is demo text"""

pw.text_to_handwriting(txt, "hand1.png", [0, 0, 138])
print("End")
```

I was trying to convert my normal text into handwriting and got this error.

Comment: Post entire code